# How to send text from the textbox to the actionResult?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a question about MVC4 (Razor). I have page where I want to filter data. There is a textbox (input) and a submit button. I want to move the text in the textbox to the actionresult. How can I resolve this?

On my page I've the following row:

```
@{ using (Html.BeginForm("Experiences"))
   {
      <span class="label">Filter on:</span><input id="FilterText" type="text" size="50"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="knowledge" /><br />
    }
}
<br />
```

And I want to call the ActionResult Experiences

```
    public ActionResult Experiences(string knowledge = "")
    {
        ReadExperienceData(knowledge);
        return View(ListOfExperiences);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the `name` property value of the input element same as the action method parameter name.

```
<input id="FilterText" name="knowledge " type="text" size="50"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submitKnowledge" />
```

Also it looks like you are not using the `Beginform` method properly. You may try any of the below overloads, as needed

```
@using(Html.Beginform("Knowledge","YourControllerName"))
{
  //form elements
}
```

or

```
@using(Html.Beginform())
{
  //form elements
}
```